# Tesnorflow data.dataset.from_tesnor_slices throwing error

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, audio-processing

My aim is to process a data set of audio files and corresponding transcript and feed it to a neural network.
I have a dataframe that contains file name and corresponding transcript.

I want to use

```
tensorflow.data.dataset.from_tensor_slices
```

to create a data pipeline. Mainly because as compared to manual methods its has lazy execution.

I have written a function as follows

```
def create_dataset(audio_file, label):
    # Parameters for librosa.stft function
    frame_length = 256
    frame_step = 160
    fft_length = 384

    audio_file = audio_file.numpy().decode('utf-8')

      # Function to load and process audio file
    def load_and_process_audio(audio_file):
      y, sr = librosa.load(path+audio_file, sr=16000)
      stft = librosa.stft(y, n_fft=fft_length, hop_length=frame_step)
      spectrogram = np.abs(stft)
      spectrogram = librosa.util.fix_length(spectrogram, size=1000, axis=1)
      return tf.convert_to_tensor(spectrogram.T)
    
       
    # Function to convert transcription to labels
    
     label = tf.convert_to_tensor(label)
     label = tf.strings.lower(label)
     label = tf.strings.unicode_split(label,input_encoding = "UTF-8")
     y = char_to_num(label)
     target_length = 200
     y = tf.pad(y, paddings  = [[0, target_length-tf.shape(y)[0]]], mode = 'CONSTANT', constant_values  = 0 )
   
    

     
  
    
    # Apply load_and_process_audio function to all clips in dataframe
    X = load_and_process_audio(audio_file)
    
    # Convert transcriptions to labels
    
    
    return X, y
```

I am creating dataset as follows: Note as I am using librosa to create spectrogram so I need to convert tensor back to numpy and then back.

```
batch_size = 32
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((list(df_train['Clips_name']), list(df_train['transcription'])))
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda audio_file, label: tf.py_function(create_dataset, [audio_file, label], [tf.float32, tf.int32]),
    num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE).padded_batch(batch_size, padded_shapes=([None, None], [None])).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

When trying to confirm shape of X & Y I am getting error.

```
for x, y in train_dataset:
  print(x.shape, y.shape)
```

ERROR MESSAGE

(32, 1000, 193) (32, 200)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)  in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 for x, y in train_dataset:
2   print(x.shape, y.shape)

3 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)    7260 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):    7261   e.message += (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
-> 7262   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access    7263     7264

UnknownError: {{function_node
_*wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_2_device*/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.   (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT: {{function_node
_*wrapped__Reshape_device*/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 128 values, but the requested shape has 153   [[{{node Reshape}}]]    [[tensor/_2]]   (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT: {{function_node
_*wrapped__Reshape_device*/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 128 values, but the requested shape has 153   [[{{node Reshape}}]]    [[tensor/_1]] 0 successful operations. 0 derived errors ignored. [Op:Reshape] Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 265, in **call**
return func(device, token, args)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 143, in **call**
outputs = self._call(device, args)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 150, in _call
ret = self._func(*args)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 642, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "", line 21, in create_dataset
label = tf.strings.unicode_split(label,input_encoding = "UTF-8")

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 7262, in raise_from_not_ok_status
raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.   (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT: {{function_node
_*wrapped__Reshape_device*/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 128 values, but the requested shape has 153   [[{{node Reshape}}]]    [[tensor/_2]]   (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT: {{function_node
_*wrapped__Reshape_device*/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 128 values, but the requested shape has 153   [[{{node Reshape}}]]    [[tensor/_1]] 0 successful operations. 0 derived errors ignored. [Op:Reshape]

```
 [[EagerPyFunc]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

Issue is arising in producing label

I have already done padding to make sure that labels are produced of uniform length , however I am getting error
Input to reshape is a tensor with 128 values, but the requested shape has 153

I am not sure why is this the case and what does it mean as I have done implicit conversion?

Comment: Do not include text/code as images, only as plain text